# timer reset when browser is refreshed and closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

how to make my timer not reset when browser is refreshed and closed?

i us blog=blogger

my problem here is when i press refresh the timer restarts to its original time.
How can i make the timer not reset when i click refresh button or when i close the browser ?

Here's my code

Here are exmeple : https://jsfiddle.net/okL8z9z0/

linkforyouTimermylinkhiReady

```js
function secondsTimeSpanToHMS(s) {
  var h = Math.floor(s / 3600);
  s -= h * 3600;
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  s -= m * 60;
  return h + ":" + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ":" + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s);
}


$(function() {

  $(".flink").click(function() {
    var timer = $(this).parent().parent().find('.timer');
    if (timer.data('secleft') <= 0) {
      timer.data('secleft', timer.data('minutes') * 60 + 20);
      $(this).parent().fadeTo(300, 0.3);
      $(this).parent().next().fadeTo(300, 0.3);
      $.post("", {
        fid: $(this).data('fid')
      });
    }
  });







  $(".timer").click(function() {
    if (confirm("Reset timer?")) {
      $(this).data('secleft', 0);
      $.post("", {
        fid: $(this).closest("tr").find('a:eq(0)').data('fid'),
        reset: 1
      });
    }
  });






  var lasttime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
  var curtime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);

  function timer() {
    curtime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
    $(".timer").each(function() {
      if ($(this).data('secleft') > 0) {
        $(this).data('secleft', $(this).data('secleft') - (curtime - lasttime));
        $(this).text(secondsTimeSpanToHMS($(this).data('secleft')));
      } else {
        if ($(this).text() != $("#language").data('ready')) {
          $(this).text($("#language").data('ready'));
          $(this).parent().prev().fadeTo(300, 1);
          $(this).parent().prev().prev().fadeTo(300, 1);
        }
      }
    });
    lasttime = curtime;
    setTimeout(timer, 1000);
  }
  timer();


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DIV CLASS="box" STYLE="width:100%">
  <TABLE STYLE="width:100%">
    <TR>
      <TH STYLE="width:220px">link</TH>
      <TH STYLE="width:140px">foryou</TH>
      <TH STYLE="width:140px">Timer</TH>
      <TH/>
    </TR>
    <TR data-payout="900">
      <TD>
        <A CLASS="flink" HREF="https://www.google.com" TARGET="_blank">mylink</A>
      </TD>
      <TD>hi</TD>
      <TD>
        <SPAN CLASS="timer" data-minutes="1" data-secleft="0">Ready</SPAN>
      </TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Store value in cookie or localstorage.

Comment: i need code for cookie or localstorage and work with blog

Comment: So set the value in a cookie or localstorage and read it when the page loads. Pretty basic concept. If it is there use it, if not do what you do not to initiate the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every data from JavaScript is removed when tab or browser is refreshed or closed - it's normal. If you need to store your timer, you can use cookies and save data about timer in `timer()` function. For example:

```
function timer() {
curtime = Math.round($.now() / 1000);
document.cookie="cookie_name="+curtime; // save curtime variable to cookie_name cookie
$(".timer").each(function() {
  if ($(this).data('secleft') > 0) {
    $(this).data('secleft', $(this).data('secleft') - (curtime - lasttime));
    $(this).text(secondsTimeSpanToHMS($(this).data('secleft')));
  } else {
    if ($(this).text() != $("#language").data('ready')) {
      $(this).text($("#language").data('ready'));
      $(this).parent().prev().fadeTo(300, 1);
      $(this).parent().prev().prev().fadeTo(300, 1);
    }
  }
});
lasttime = curtime;
setTimeout(timer, 1000);
}
timer();
```

If you would like to read your cookie with last curtime value, you can do it by get `document.cookie` value and split (or parse) it for retrieve your value.

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) you have some information about cookies API and examples of use (also ready functions for cookies management).

Answer (score 0):

when page refresh the data vanish so we need to store the hours,min and second somewhere and the best and easy way to do is localStorage. so at the first time when the timer start then store the hour,min and second after then get the hh,mm,ss from there so it will not vanish the timer when its refresh.gd luck

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible, because if you refresh the page the browser re-run your javascript code. Best you can do is to store your current time in cookie, local storage or on some backend-server before page re-loading and when page reloads then you start your timer from current time.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda I think comment is just for getting information about the question.

Comment: epascarello's comment is similar to yours, and is a comment. I see what you're saying, but concise answers like this should be comments as well.